# Boundedness of variants of discrete Hilbert transform.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is known that for $p>1$ the operator  $H(a_n)=\sum_{n\neq m} \frac{a_n}{n-m}$ is a bounded linear operator from $\ell^p$ to $\ell^p$. Now, for a fixed $\beta>0$, is $H(a_n)=\sum_{\beta n\neq m} \frac{a_n}{\beta n-m}$ also a bounded linear mapping from $\ell^p$ to $\ell^p$? Any reference or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer covering the case $\beta\in \mathbb{Q}_+.$ Let $H_\beta $ denote the modified transform, while $H$ is the standard one. Assume $\beta={k\over l}.$ For a sequence $a\in \ell^p$ let $c$ be defined by $$c_n=\begin{cases}a_{n/k} & n/k\in \mathbb{N}\\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Similarly for $b\in \ell^q$ let
$$d_m=\begin{cases}b_{m/l} & m/l\in \mathbb{N}\\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $c\in \ell^p,$  $\|c\|_p=\|a\|_p$ and $d\in \ell^q,$  $\|d\|_q=\|b\|_q$
Next
$$\sum_m\sum_{\beta n\neq  m}{a_nb_m\over \beta n -m} =l\sum_m\sum_{k n\neq  lm}{a_nb_m\over k n -lm} \\ =l\sum_m\sum_{k n\neq  lm}{c_{kn}d_{lm}\over kn-lm}=l\sum_v\sum_{u \neq  v}{c_ub_v\over u -v}$$
Therefore $\langle H_\beta a,b\rangle =l\langle Hc,d\rangle.$ Hence
$$|\langle H_\beta a,b\rangle|=l|\langle Hc,d\rangle|$$ Therefore
$$\|H_\beta\|_{p\to p} \le l\|H\|_{p\to p}\quad (*)$$

Comment: Thanks. Rational case seems to be way approachable than irrational case. I haven't seen any result about irrational case up to this point.

Comment: I have tried general case by discretization of the continuous Hilbert transform, for which the boundedness of your modification is obvious by change of variables. However dealing with discretization I have encountered   an obstacle when $\beta$ was not rational.